# Blackworms and aquariums

Tags: aquarium, pest-control, live-food

I just started to study the topic of cold water aquariums. I ended up quite quickly to [this site](https://aquariumtidings.com/how-to-culture-blackworms-black-worms/), offering some insight on how to grow blackworms as food for fish.

The end of the story gave me mixed feelings. While I understand partially the point of the warning, I see it more as a "I want it!" - I will give up the worry of feeding the fish ;)

> If you feed more worms than the fish can quickly eat, they may establish themselves in your tank, and there is nothing that ruins a show tank faster, than hundreds of little worms waving at the bottom.

Also, that statement somehow conflicts with another statement earlier in the article:

> A blackworm culture will be able to provide a few worms a day for harvesting – but anymore and you will quickly deplete the culture.

Now which one is true? Hundreds of worms breeding out of control? Or quick depletion is at the horizon?

And, do you have the experience of the worms on the bottom of the aquarium? Do they look really horror? I am especially interested in personal experience with the topic.

Comment: Maybe the two citations are with different circumstances? One speaks about worms in you fish tank and the other about an extra worm tank I assume.

Comment: Yes and no. The idea of the second quote is that if the fish eat more than a few worms per day, the worms population will finish "fast", regardless in which tank they live. At least, according to my understanding. Of course, the assumption is that the tank has enough fish to eat more than a few worms a day.

Comment: The difference is the living circumstances. In the real tank they could hide and have more food I think. So they will grow more than in the worm tank I assume.

Comment: I did not think of that. Good point.